# Is there a work-around solution to restrict a search to a specific sourcebook?

Tags: dnd-5e, tools, books, dnd-beyond

I know that the D&D Beyond search engine lacks a filter for specific sourcebooks, but is there are work-around that lets you restrict the search to a selected sourcebook?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132522/discussion-between-akixkisu-and-rallozarx).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### On the mobile app.

The site does not have this functionality outside of searching compendium chapters with ctrl + f. However, the mobile app does. Selecting a book and then the search bar allows you to search within a single book:

[image]

My experience using the mobile app for searching is that it is actually quite good, which makes the full website’s search function even more hilariously terrible.

Comment: Instead of flashing sales in the top bar, they should flash basic features that should really be part of the main site to advertise their app, looks like I will have to re-install bluestacks.

Answer (score 7):

### For public sources, you can use an alternate search engine with the desired feature (but it's not great)

It appears that the freely available content on D&D Beyond is indexed by search engines, which means you can use, for example, DuckDuckGo or Google with the `site:` operator to restrict your search to a specific book, as long as that book is available for free. For example, if you want to search only in the Basic Rules for "bonus action", try searching for "[site:https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules bonus action](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.dndbeyond.com%2Fsources%2Fbasic-rules+bonus+action&ia=web)". Unfortunately, this "search interface" is not optimized for your use case: the links will only take you to the top of the relevant page, which means you have to use Control+F once you get there to find the section you're looking for.

Since this only works for the basic rules and a few other sources, it will be most useful when looking up game rules rather than game content.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the search functionality in the mobile/tablet app, most of the specific “game rules” searches can filter by source book. So if you are searching for a spell, monster, magic item, feat or background - options available under “Games Rules” in the main menu - you can restrict search results to a specific source or sources using the Advanced Filters.